# Links in drupal blocks are not working

Tags: drupal-7

I have created one drupal block containing links which are direct.
Ex:login->user/login
   register->user/register

But if i am in **user/login** link and clicking the link **user/register** the path is taking as **user/user/register**.

Please help me in this
Thank you

Comment: please add some code to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to link to /user/register so your link will be based on home path and not current path.

Or else you can use an absolute path so your link is not dependant of where you are in the site, something like :

```
<?php
$linkUrl = $base_path . '/user/register';
?>
<a href="<?php print $linkUrl; ?> title="Link to user/register">
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7

Comment: <div class="header_links" id="header-links">
 <a href="user/register">Join Us</a> /<a href="user/register"> Sign Up</a> | <a href="content/help-and-security-0">Help &amp; Security</a> | <a href="content/employers-gateway-0">Employer's Gateway </a></div>

Comment: Replace all the href="user/register" by href="/user/register" and you should be fine.

Comment: See this answer for explanations about absolute and relative path : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls

Answer (score 0):

Use the `url` function:

```
$login_url = url('user');
$register_url = url('user/register');
```